langchain huggingface hub invoking issue
I wanted to create a ReAct Agent in langchain, it always didn't work, and when I invoked the llm itself (not the agent) I found out that its response starts with the input and then with the response
for example
model = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1")
print(model.invoke("hello how are you doing?")

answer: "hello how are you doing?\nHey! im good thanks."
Does anyone know how to solve this issue and simply get the answer?
